# Git Rebase and squash in sub branch

Tags: git

I am working on git master and sub branch. **Master** and **subcode** Branch.

Now I have done one change in **subcode** branch and commit(4 to 5 commits done) that changes and push over **subcode** branch.

Now I want to show only one commit in my **subcode** branch but currently its show me 5 commits.

I have used following command for rebase the commits.

```
git rebase -interactive HEAD~3
```

And then perform some edits like this.

```
pick 6336d7c Commit commit#1
pick 54e8a9b Commit commit#2
pick 39f1d2h Commit commit#3 

git rebase --continue
```

But it still show me 5 commits. Is there any idea how can I squash and rebase all commit into one commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the editor opens with the selected commits, change `pick` with `squash`. So it should like something like this if you want to `squash` all commits into the #1:

1. pick 6336d7c Commit commit#1
2. squash 54e8a9b Commit commit#2
3. squash 39f1d2h Commit commit#3

Then save, exit the editor and execute:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use: git `rebase -i <after-this-commit>` and then replace "pick" on the second and subsequent commits with "squash" or "fixup".
refer https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode